# How to perform image processing using the "12 factor app" way in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, imagemagick, image-uploading, 12factor

I'm having a hard time figuring out the best way to do image uploads in my Rails project while still adhering the the '12 factor app' standards.

Basically, I would like to have users upload their own profile images. I know I can use Paperclip to accomplish that, but I still need to use something like ImageMagick to resize the images and prepare the pictures to be used in my application.

According to 12 Factor app's Section 2, Dependencies (http://12factor.net/dependencies):

> A twelve-factor app never relies on implicit existence of system-wide packages.
>
> Twelve-factor apps also do not rely on the implicit existence of any system tools. Examples include shelling out to ImageMagick or curl.

It says you shouldn't use ImageMagick locally. That makes sense, but how would you do you image processing then?

Thanks in advance for any advice you can give!

Answer (score 4):

I think the key word there is *implicit*.

Make dependencies explicit, and account for behaviors if some required component you don't ship is not present. There are ton's of environment management tools that let you stand up a new environment configured in the 'proper' way.

I tend to think of ImageMagick as a backing service, akin to the database your application uses. I don't believe 12-factor is telling you that you have to also ship the RDBMS in order to be totally self-contained.

Perhaps some configuration values where if specified, then the ImageMagick libraries are used, or degrade gracefully until libraries are loaded and configured.

Yeah, it's a sticky wicket.

Comment: I think I can pick up what you're throwing down :) Basically, it would be acceptable to rely on ImageMagick if my deployment process is using something like Chef that will make sure that IMageMagick is available on any system. That sound about right?

Either that, or image processing would have to be handled by an attached resource (much like your database example). Instead of just calling ImageMagick directly, I would call a URL service (another server in my network) to process that images for the app. Right?